# Why is there no nullpointerexception for the canvas methods inside onDraw method?

Tags: android, canvas

I am trying to draw a rectangle using onDraw method which as Canvas object has parameter. When the drawRect method is called from the onDraw method using canvas object how is the canvas object initialized.

I tried initializing new object for Canvas class inside onDraw method. But the output shows a blank screen.

```
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawRect(200,20,300,400,paint);

    }
}
```

How is the Canvas object canvas is initialized? If not required in what situations does nullpointerexception occurs?

Comment: did you set a color for `Paint` object?

Comment: Yes, I am getting a output. but my question is where is the reference variable of Canvas canvas is initialized.

Comment: the system creates a canvas while constructing your `View`. canvas can't be null, NPE can't be thrown. it's the same as the bundle argument in `onSaveInstanceState` can't be initialized as null by the system.

Answer (score 2):

Your View is responsible for creating your fragment and if you want to draw anything on Your view then you have to use the canvas instance provided by your view, `View's canvas cannot be null`.

If you check source code of android then you will find a variable named [**mCanvas**](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#26772) declaration that you manipulate in your `onDraw()` method call.

If you want to know how View instantiate the canvas [**check here**](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#19557).

if You want to manipulate the canvas just manipulate the Canvas instance onDraw()

```
 privat Paint paint;

 //call this method in constructor of your View
 void setPaint(){
      this.paint = new Paint();
      this.paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      this.paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
      this.paint.setStrokeWidth(10.0F);
      this.paint.setAntiAlias(true);
      this.paint.setDither(true);
    }
 //should be called from constructor(anywhere else before invalidating View) setWillNotDraw(false) then only onDraw of View will be called.
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawRect(200,20,300,400,paint);
    }
}
```

*This is how android instantiate there canvas:[Source Code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#19557)*

> ```
>         Canvas canvas;
>         if (attachInfo != null) {
>             canvas = attachInfo.mCanvas;
>             if (canvas == null) {
>                 canvas = new Canvas();
>             }
>             canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
>             // Temporarily clobber the cached Canvas in case one of our children
>             // is also using a drawing cache. Without this, the children would
>             // steal the canvas by attaching their own bitmap to it and bad, bad
>             // thing would happen (invisible views, corrupted drawings, etc.)
>             attachInfo.mCanvas = null;
>         } else {
>             // This case should hopefully never or seldom happen
>             canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
>         }
>         if (clear) {
>             bitmap.eraseColor(drawingCacheBackgroundColor);
>         }
>         computeScroll();
>         final int restoreCount = canvas.save();
>         if (autoScale && scalingRequired) {
>             final float scale = attachInfo.mApplicationScale;
>             canvas.scale(scale, scale);
>         }
>         canvas.translate(-mScrollX, -mScrollY);
>         mPrivateFlags |= PFLAG_DRAWN;
>         if (mAttachInfo == null || !mAttachInfo.mHardwareAccelerated ||
>                 mLayerType != LAYER_TYPE_NONE) {
>             mPrivateFlags |= PFLAG_DRAWING_CACHE_VALID;
>         }
>         // Fast path for layouts with no backgrounds
>         if ((mPrivateFlags & PFLAG_SKIP_DRAW) == PFLAG_SKIP_DRAW) {
>             mPrivateFlags &= ~PFLAG_DIRTY_MASK;
>             dispatchDraw(canvas);
>             drawAutofilledHighlight(canvas);
>             if (mOverlay != null && !mOverlay.isEmpty()) {
>                 mOverlay.getOverlayView().draw(canvas);
>             }
>         } else {
>             draw(canvas);
>         }
>         canvas.restoreToCount(restoreCount);
>         canvas.setBitmap(null);
>         if (attachInfo != null) {
>             // Restore the cached Canvas for our siblings
>             attachInfo.mCanvas = canvas;
>         }
> ```